# Custom editor method called by inspector view button

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a method that reads all assets from a folder and creates a file with an enum containing all the files in the folder.
How can i run it by pressing a button in the inspector? All the custom Editor tutorials i watch shows that a custom editor must be connected to a class that its supposed to edit and that just doesnt apply in my case.

```
public class EnumGeneratorTool : Editor
{
    [SerializeField]
    string sourcePath;

    [SerializeField]
    string outputPath;

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawDefaultInspector();

        if (GUILayout.Button("Do Thing"))
        {
            // I want thnis to happen when Do Thing button is pressed
            Debug.Log("Do the thing: " + sourcePath);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a menu to this so won't need a extra gameobject to hold your script. Here's the code.

`public class CustomMenu {`

```
// Add a menu item named "Do Something" to MyMenu in the menu bar.
[MenuItem("MyMenu/Do Something")]
static void DoSomething()
{
    Debug.Log("Doing Something...");
}
```

}

If it compiles correctly, you should see a the custom menu in the menu bar.
[image]

**EDIT:**
Monobehaviour component to be attached to gameobject.

`public class Parser : MonoBehaviour {`

```
public string path = "";

public void DoSomething()
{
    Debug.Log("Doing Something with path.");
}
```

}

Editor class. (Must be inside "Editor" folder to work properly).

`using UnityEditor;`

[CustomEditor(typeof(Parser))]
public class ParserEditor : Editor{

```
public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{
    Parser myTarget = (Parser)target;

    DrawDefaultInspector();

    if (GUILayout.Button("Do Thing"))
    {
        // I want thnis to happen when Do Thing button is pressed
        Debug.Log("Do the thing: " + myTarget.path);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Make sure to add "using UnityEditor;" at the top.

Comment: Thanks! But i have som arguments that i want exposed in the inspector. So i want it to be attached on a GameObject. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes you can. You need a monobehavious class (which has the string variable exposed) and an editor class(where you create the button) that should be inside "Editor" folder. Attached the monobehaviour class to any gameobject in the scene and you should see the button you made in the editor class. See updated answer.